# Node.js get all running processes

Tags: node.js, process

How can I get all current running process on my node server? I tried using ps-node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node) but failed to fetch the list.

I'm looking for something like the following command in C#:

```
// Get all processes running on the local computer.
Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: are you looking for pids?

Comment: @Freakinator pids and names

Comment: From the command line, we use the [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) tool.

From inside a server I would do something fancy (like spawning a subprocess which gets the pids and names from the forever output and collect the results in the node instance), but I'm not sure if it's the way to do it...

Comment: @Freakinator Can you write a small example and get the points for this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the above mentioned [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) tool, gnu [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) and the built-in [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) node library:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    forever    = spawn('forever', ['list', '--plain']),
    awk  = spawn('awk', ['NR>2{print $4,$5,$6,$7,"\t",$9}']);

forever.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  awk.stdin.write(data);
});

forever.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('forever stderr: ' + data);
});

forever.on('close', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log('forever process exited with code ' + code);
  }
  awk.stdin.end();
});

awk.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  // data is your result as Buffer
  // print data as string
  console.log('' + data);
});

awk.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('awk stderr: ' + data);
});

awk.on('close', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log('awk process exited with code ' + code);
  }
});
```

What's happening here, basically is:

```
$ forever list --plain | awk '{NR>2{print $4,$5,$6,$7,"\t",$9}}'
```

Of course, the variables awk prints depend on the `forever list` output... To test the correct solution I would start from printing `$0` to get the whole output, then trim it down such that it reports only the informations you need.